# converting four floats in xmm3 to four ints in memory

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, sse2

I am newbie to sse, and I have trouble to find it,
please tell me what is the good way to convert 
(truncate as in "(int) float_") four packed floats 
I have in xmm3 register into four ints and store 
it into memory (some like "movaps oword [edx+32], xmm3 "
storing is clear but i do not find just how to convert)

Comment: You can save yourself a lot of grief by using intrinsics rather than trying to do this in raw asm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use intrinsics if you value your sanity (and free time):

```
int32_t *dest;
__m128 vf = _mm_set_ps(4.0f, 3.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f);
__m128i vi = _mm_cvttps_epi32(vf); // 4 x float -> 4 x int (with truncation)
_mm_store_epi32(dest, vi); // NB: use _mm_storeu_epi32 if `dest` not aligned
```

If you must use asm for some reason the the corresponding instruction for `_mm_cvttps_epi32` is `cvttps2dq`.

Comment: alrrite `cvtps2dq xmm3, xmm3` worked, (i thoud there is no such thing (somewhat lost in sse mnemonics) but there it is)

Comment: Get the AVX intrinsics guide form Intel's AVX page - it has all the SSE intrinsics and instructions (as well as AVX of course) in a nice summary format in a standalone utility for Linux/Windows/Mac.